# Bounds on Twitter rate limits: the `reset` field

Tags: r, web-scraping, twitter

In [Twitter Developer Agreement and Policy](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/agreement-and-policy), rate limits are defined. See also: [rate limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits) and [rate limiting](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting). (I'm using `twitteR` in `R`.) From these documents, I don't understand whether there are limits to the maximum number of tweets that I can scrape in a week (e.g.). E.g., what happens if I scrape 20,000 or 40,000 tweets every day?

**EDIT**

As suggested my comment, I used:

```
twitteR::getCurRateLimitInfo(resources=resource_families)
```

obtaining, after having executed a Twitter search, the columns `limit` and `remaining` equal exept for `/account/settings` (from 15 to 14), `/application/rate_limit_status` (from 180 to 179). I also executed

```
    twitteR::getCurRateLimitInfo(resources=resource_families)
```

before and after the Twitter search, and the only thing that changes is the `reset` (from 14:13:52 to 17:32:58). What does it mean? Does it increase every Twitter search? Does it decrease if I do not perform Twitter search?

Comment: Have you tried this function to check your status? `twitterR::getCurRateLimitInfo(resources=resource_families, ...)`

Comment: @Dave2e, yes but: `twitteR::getCurRateLimitInfo(resources=resource_families, ...)` returned `Error: '...' used in an incorrect context`

Comment: Please check for the proper usage and example by going to the help menu, `?getCurRateLimitInfo`

Comment: It works! I'm updating the question.

Comment: Perform a search on this site for "[r] Rate Limit in Twitter" there are several questions/answers that may help you.